# UTF-8 output from Socialcast Rest Api service

Tags: java, rest, curl, utf-8, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Socialcast rest api with CURL. Here is my curl command,

```
`curl -k -X GET -v --basic -u "email:password" https://<dpmain>.socialcast.com/api/messages/18755210.json`
```

The output for above command is,

```
{"message":{"id":18755210,"user":{"id":964633,"name":"username","url":"myrepo","username":"myname","active":true,"te
rminated":false,"inactive":false,"role":"member","type":"User","title":"SE","out_of_office":false,"back_in_office_on":null,"company_login":null},"title":"","body":"\"\u
0db8\u0dad\u0dca \u0d9a\u0dd4\u0da9\u0dd4 \u0d9a\u0db1\u0dca\u0da7\u0dda\u0db1\u0dbb\u0dba \u0dc3\u0db8\u0dca\u0db6\u0db1\u0dca\u0db0 \u0dc3\u0dd2\u0daf\u0dca\u0db0\u0d
d2\u0dba\u0dda\u0daf\u0dd3 \u0d85\u0d9c\u0db8\u0dd0\u0dad\u0dd2\u0dc0\u0dba\u0dcf\u0d9c\u0dda \u0dbb\u0dd9\u0daf\u0dca\u0daf \u0d9a\u0dd0\u0d9e\u0dd3 \u0db1\u0dd2\u0dbb
\u0dd4\u0dc0\u0dad \u0db4\u0dda\u0db1\u0dca\u0db1\u0dda \u0da2\u0dcf\u0dad\u0dd2\u0d9a \u0dc4\u0dd9\u0dc5 \"","action":"","verb":null,"message_type":"status_message","i
con":null,
"external_url":"","created_at":"2013-12-14T14:43:01+00:00","updated_at":"2013-12-14T14:43:01+00:00","likes":[],"likes_count":0,"comments":[],"comments_count":0,"attachm
ents":[],"media_files":[],"contains_url_only":true,"external_resources":[],"tags":[],"last_interacted_at":1387032181,"group":{},"category_id":null,"recipients":[],"thum
bnail_url":null,"player_url":null,"player_params":null,"likable":false,"ratable":false,"rating":null,"ratings_average":null,"ratings_count":null,"editable":true,"deleta
ble":true,"watchable":false,"watch":null,"flag":null,"source":{"name":"web","formal_name":"Web App","id":"web"},"poll":null,"embed":null,"hidden":null,"subscribed":null
,"groups":[],"extensions":[],"new_group_id":null,"new_group_archived_at":null,"days_of_stickiness":0,"sticky_for_current_user":false}}* Connection #0 to host left intact
```

As you can see I am getting characters like \u0da7\u0dda\u0db1\u0dbb in response. Are they UTF-8 characters? How can I get readable character set out of this with Java?
Actually I should get following readable characters (those are in sinhala language) instated of those,
"මත් කුඩු කන්ටේනරය සම්බන්ධ සිද්ධියේදී අගමැතිවයාගේ රෙද්ද කැඞී නිරුවත පේන්නේ ජාතික හෙළ "

Anyway I am using windows command prompt to execute curl command. Also I tried by specifying the content type header in the request as follows but same result.
"Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"

Also insteaded of curl I tried with simple java program (apache http client) with eclipse and got the same result by writing to the file.

Let me know how I can get readable characters from above.

Note:
If I execute this rest service with chrome advanced rest client I can get readable characters. But raw output in advanced rest client has the same unreadable characters.

Regards,
-Lasith.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert these into readable string from your code. You can use something like below:

```
String unicode = "\u0db8\u0dad\u0dca \u0d9a\u0dd4\u0da9\u0dd4";
String string = new String(unicode.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(string);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Here the issue is call to rest api get string like "\u0db8\u0dad\u0dca.." So java representation of it like "\\u0db8\\u0dad\\u0dca .." . E.g if you have a text file with "\u0db8\u0dad\u0dca.." how can you read it from java program and take readable characters out of it? `BufferedReader  br =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Lasith\\testfile.txt"));
    String sCurrentLine;
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
      println(sCurrentLine);      

      String string = new String(sCurrentLine.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
      println(string);
    }`

Comment: Yes, something like your this should be able to read the text from file and able to print. Just make sure your console has the proper encoding to display the unicode text.